# Convert Varchar to Float MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to convert some data I inherited from varchar to float:

> ```
> SELECT CAST([Column 8] AS Int)    FROM [Sean].[dbo].[ResApr2019]
> ```

I get this error:

> > Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '   14,714.000 ' to data type int.

Any ideas how to get around this?

Thanks,

Comment: Try `TRY_CAST` if  can not convert some value instead of ERROR for this value will be NULL

Comment: int is integer, whole number. float is a floating point. try SELECT CAST([Column 8] AS float)    FROM [Sean].[dbo].[ResApr2019]

Comment: @DavidSöderlund There will still be an error for `14,714.000`

Comment: Why are you storing numbers as an `varchar` in the first place?

Comment: @Larnu - I've inherited The data, not my choice to store it like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

remove ',' from the text, try to convert it to decimal and then integer value.

```
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(11,0), REPLACE('14,714.000', ',', ''))
```

In your case

```
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(11,0),REPLACE([Column 8],',','')) FROM [Sean].[dbo].[ResApr2019]
```

OR

```
 SELECT CONVERT(float,REPLACE([Column 8],',','')) FROM [Sean].[dbo].[ResApr2019]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your datatype(s). `varchar` is not a numerical datatype and shouldn't be used to store numerical values. This is why you're getting the error as a numerical datatype doesn't contain commas. You can fix your tables with the following statements (assuming that they are all in a format `%,0.000`):

```
USE Sean;
GO
UPDATE TABLE dbo.ResApr2019
SET [LENGTH] = REPLACE([Column 8],',','');
ALTER TABLE A ALTER COLUMN [Column 8] int; --Other datatype with a scale/precision may be appropriate (like decimal)
```

Then you can run your query without having to `CAST`:

```
SELECT [Column 8]
FROM [Sean].[dbo].[ResApr2019];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Money` data type instead of `float`. `money` will handle comma separated numbers.

```
select cast([Column 8] as money) from [sean].[dbo].[ResApr2019]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails because of comma and dot in your string. You want to eliminate those characters before converting to INT

```
 DECLARE @A VARCHAR(10) = '14,714.000'

DECLARE @B VARCHAR(20)
SET @B = REPLACE(REPLACE(@A, ',', ''), '.', '')

SELECT CAST(@A AS INT)--This code fails
SELECT CAST(@B AS INT)--This code works well
```

in your case:

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE([Column 8],',',''),'.','') AS Int)    FROM [Sean].[dbo].[ResApr2019]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be the comma in the varchar value. By stripping it out before you do the cast or convert you will fix the issue. Did you restore this database locally from a backup on another server by any chance? It may be a case that your Region settings on your local machine differ from that of the server.

```
declare @test varchar(50) = replace('14,714.000 ', ',', '');
select @test;
select cast(@test as float)
select convert(float, @test)
```

Comment: Can you add a short description?

Comment: @help-info.de hope the comments above make things a little clearer

Comment: thanks, you know - code-only answers are considered low quality.